# What is the milk in Bratwurst for?

Tags: substitutions, sausages

I'm looking at making homemade kosher bratwurst and I picked up [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1631590731) to get a general idea of the recipes.  I was surprised to find that many of the brat recipes call for either one cup of cream or one ounce of powdered milk per 5 pounds of meat.  Many recipes online also call for dry milk but I haven't seen an explanation.

What is dairy doing for these recipes?  If it's just for flavor I could omit it, but I'm worried it adds something important to the recipe.  If that's the case, I'm interested in finding a suitable substitute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*None* of the DIY-Bratwurst recipes I know over here (Germany) contains milk or cream (although in general we love milk and add it almost everywhere :-) ).
The general composition is always meat (lean + fatty to arrive at 20 - 30 % fat), spices (salt, pepper, herbs, possibly garlic). Homemade Bratwurst usually avoids adding water/ice, and also avoids starchy components - they are mostly seen as cheap components to dilute the Bratwurst in commercial settings.

OTOH, a friend with milk allergy always asks specifically when buying ready-made Bratwurst to be on the safe side, and told me they sometimes contain milk/cream.

The [Austrian Codex Alimentarius](https://verbrauchergesundheit.gv.at/lebensmittel/buch/codex/B14_Fleisch_und_Fleischerzeugnisse.pdf) lists milk as possible ingredient only with very few sausage types. (And in general is more concerned with limiting the amount of water and starch in commercial Bratwurst)

---

The predominant meat for Bratwurst over here is pork, which is rather fat compared to other meats (also Speck is often added to Bratwurst that uses lean non-pork meats such as game).
If you have looked for pork-free Bratwurst recipes, the required amount of fat needs to come from somewhere and that may be the reason for e.g. adding cream as an easily availabe non-pork source of animal fat (maybe try goose fat?).

Comment: I took this as a blessing to avoid the milk and just do meat + fat + spices.  I had trouble getting fatty meat and ended up using beef ribs in there since it was the fattiest cut I could get and supplementing with some non-dairy butter substitute.  They turned out great.